# Parsing JSON and deleting objects from it is giving error

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I have a phonegap application and I want to prune the pictures before downloading.
I am passing a JSON object to my function which is

```
[{"name":"aaa.jpg","link":"https:\/\/www.abc.com\/aaa.jpg"},"name":"bbb.jpg","link":"https:\/\/www.abc.com\/\/bbb.jpg"}]
```

And using the following function to parse and delete

```
function prunePictures(pictures) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
            var name = entries[i].name;
            $.each(pictures, function(i, obj) {
                if (obj.name == name) {
                    delete pictures[i];
                }
            });
     }
}
```

But its not going through the loop and I am getting an error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: Then either `entries[i]` or `obj` evaluates to undefined. Which one, and why?

Comment: In your debugging environment, add a console.log(entries[i]) at the beginning of the for loop.
Add a console.log(obj) or console.log(i) at the beginning of the each function.  
This should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Yep, the JSON is missing a `{`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...you don't want to delete the picture object.
You want to splice it out of the array.

Deleting it leaves a hole in the array, whereas splicing it removes the hole.

```
var l = entries.length, i = 0, pictureName;

for (; i < l; i += 1) {
    pictureName = entries[i].name;
    pictures.forEach(function (picture, i, arr) {
        if (pictureName === picture.name) { arr.splice(i, 1); }
    });
}
```

Removes the object in pictures if an object in entities has the same `name` property.

Comment: **Thank you very much**. This code worked for me. And I apologize to the others about the missing "{" which was a typo. Thanks to all for posting out replies.It helped me debug my code. @agreco: $grep didn't work in my case but now I know its use. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your json string is missing a brace:

```
[{"name":"aaa.jpg","link":"https:\/\/www.abc.com\/aaa.jpg"},{"name":"bbb.jpg","link":"https:\/\/www.abc.com\/\/bbb.jpg"}]
```

#### Edit

I think your json just had a typo, since that's not the error you would get.

You shouldn't delete out of a `$.each` instead you should use `$.grep`

see info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

```
pictures = $.grep(pictures, function(obj,i) {
    if (obj.name == name) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```